# PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR even tough I'm specifying the model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm building a scope for a model to render some sort of randomness in a collection :

```
scope :biased_random, -> (value) {
      self.select("*, RANDOM() * (to_char(created_at, 'YYYYMMDD')::float / to_char(now(), 'YYYYMMDD')::float) AS randomable_int").order(randomable_int: :desc)
}
```

I'm satisfied with the results BUT I'm getting a `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR` :

```
"PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference \"created_at\" is ambiguous\nLINE 1: SELECT *, RANDOM() * (to_char(created_at, 'YYYYMMDD')::float...\n                                      ^\n"
```

SO I tried to specify the model name as it shouldn't be ambiguous anymore:

```
self.select("*, RANDOM() * (to_char(#{self.model.to_s.downcase}.created_at, 'YYYYMMDD')::float / to_char(now(), 'YYYYMMDD')::float) AS randomable_int").order(randomable_int: :desc)
```

And now I'm getting another PG error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "model name")
```

("model name" being my model obviously)

I don't understand why it is ambiguous in the first place and then why when I'm specifying it, I'm getting another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PG::AmbiguousColumn` error is most likely because your query is joining more than one table.
You'll want to prefix the `created_at` with the name of the table, not of the model - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name might help here.

Comment: You're totally right and I'm ashamed of not figuring this out. Thanks !